# How can a Bazel `repository_rule` adjust a `label_flag` (or a `config_setting` more generally)?

Tags: bazel

I can create a `label_flag` in Bazel to allow command line flags to in turn be matched with a `config_setting` in a Bazel `BUILD` file.

However, I'd like to not hard-code the default value of the `label_flag`, and instead compute a good default based on the system when evaluating a `repository_rule` (or some other part of the `WORKSPACE` file).

The best (but awful) way I've come up with to do this is to have the default value loaded from a `.bzl` file that is generated using the [`template` function](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#template) on the `repository_ctx`.

I feel like generating a new file by doing textual substitutions probably isn't the right way to do this, but I can't find anything else. Ideas? help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating a bzl file using the repository rule that inspects the host system is the only way to achieve what you need right now. So you're holding it "right" :)